# Dropdown doesn't send anything

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This is the Index action, that fills the possible Genders into the ViewBag for the dropdown selection later on. And it also would filter on the injected parameter

```
public ActionResult Index(string gender)
        {
            ViewBag.Genders = _db.Contacts.Select((x => x.Gender)).Distinct();

            var model = _db.Contacts.Where(x => x.Gender == gender || gender == null);
            return View(model);
        }
```

If I just use an Actionlink by passing in the Female, it filters fine:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show Ladies", "Index", "Contact", new { Gender = "Female"}, null)
```

However, with a dropdown, it seems not to be reacting at all. I can see the selections, but pressing the button, doesnt do anything:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new SelectList(ViewBag.Genders))
    <input type="button" value="Filter"/>
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the filter button use `<input type="submit" value="Filter"/>` using a `button` type won't actually submit the form.

Comment: oh darn. How did I miss that. Many Thanks :)

Comment: One more thing, how do I make the dropdown to be GET rather than Post, in order to see @gender=Female in the address bar?

Comment: You can use an overload of `Html.BeginForm` to set the method to GET. `Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get)`